# Sustainable business models for decentralized applications

Tags: decentralization

I have following questions in my mind regarding decentralized application -

**How to monetize the efforts of the organization who are creating decentralized applications?**

Let us consider an example of the Google and Facebook. Although they are offering their services for free they are gathering data of users and using it show relevant ads. With the help of decentralized application, the user will be an owner of data and user will able to control the access of their data.

Will users be paid for sharing their data? How will blockchain change the current data economy?

Answer (score 1):

being worked in google i think this is a very good idea.

**Will users be paid for sharing their data?**
it depends on the application if it allows people to get paid for their data.

blockchain can play a very big role in this blockchain can help in making the data and payment more secure and decentralized.

Answer (score 0):

Business and blockchain technology are different things. Your question is more about business. If talking about business, we have to rephrase your question this way: how can I (using blockchain technology) give users value so high that they will be willing to pay for it? And maybe add this: how can I protect my *know-how* from being replicated by my rivals in business and cutting off my profits?

I don't think these questions belong to these forum, you have to ask them on forums related to business.

Comment: thank you for your valuable suggestion. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not suitable for this forum indeed. But I would like to chime in with my own thoughts anyways...

The premises, that the organization that created the decentralized organization/application would need monetize from it for creating it, can be incorrect in the first place. After all, being a decentralized application, the source code is open and anyone can come and replicate what you have created.

What cannot be replicated easily though, is the peripherals keeping the application running. For example, such organization may need:

- oracles to provide source of truth to the blockchain
- rating agencies to evaluate individual actors performance
- "vigilantes" to challenge stakes in proof-of-stake designs
- or in general, any competing implementations of collaborators that connects to the decentralized organization

It is very likely that the creator of the decentralized organization are the first ones to create those peripherals, hence they earn according the rule they designed themselves. But in the long run, they have no privilege over others and anyone could replace them for those peripheral functions. In a way, the decentralized organization eliminates the possibility of being a rent-seeker (https://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/rentseeking.asp), you truly need to be useful to others to earn.